# How to remove warning in hibernate in netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on hibernate with Netbeans. When I run the file, it is running is successfully  but generates warning

```
3 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
99 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
100 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
103 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
105 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
148 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
148 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
188 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
208 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/PatientDetail.hbm.xml
264 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/PatientVisit.hbm.xml
324 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/DocTimeSlot.hbm.xml
375 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/Admin.hbm.xml
415 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/Users.hbm.xml
436 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/Invoice.hbm.xml
452 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/DocDetail.hbm.xml
469 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/Appoinment.hbm.xml
486 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : clinic/entity/RecpDetail.hbm.xml
507 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
604 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.PatientDetail -> patient_detail
615 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.PatientVisit -> patient_visit
617 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.DocTimeSlot -> doc_time_slot
618 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.Admin -> admin
619 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.Users -> users
620 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.Invoice -> invoice
621 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.DocDetail -> doc_detail
622 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.Appoinment -> appoinment
624 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: clinic.entity.RecpDetail -> recp_detail
631 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
635 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
642 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
646 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
648 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
654 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clinic_mgmt?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
656 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
933 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

How to remove this types of warnings?

Comment: Add this line to log4j.properties file. log4j.logger.org.hibernate = ERROR, stdout

Answer (score 1):

You mean this line?

```
188 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
```

Have you done what it says? it's saying to update the namespace, and to refer to the migration guide if you wish to know why...